# Why do SDL2 enumerations have high unexpected values?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I came across difficulties in debugging a SDL2 program: when I printed the values of enumerations such as `SDL_EventType` or `SDL_Keycode`, the values displayed were incredibly high and different from each other. For example, the event type `SDL_KEYDOWN` corresponded to 768 - and there aren't 769 elements in the enumeration `SDL_EventType`!

I made a little test to see if this strange behaviour was due to my program, but the behaviour was still there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_Event event;
  SDL_Window *wind = SDL_CreateWindow("ee", 700, 100, 300, 300, 0);
  while (SDL_PollEvent == 1)
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
  while (1)
  {
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT || event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
      break;
    fprintf(stderr, "type = %d\n", event.type);
    event.type = 0;
    SDL_Delay(15);
  }
  printf("%d\n", SDL_GetTicks());
  SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Printing `SDLK_DOWN`, `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` or such keywords outputs the same result than the previous program, which is coherent. But why are these values not coherent with the enumeration type?

Comment: Is your question why were these particular values chosen for the enumeration values? Or why they are not just strictly increasing from 0 or 1?

Comment: the latter, and it has been nicely answered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at `SDL_events.h` then you'll see something like:

```
/* Window events */
SDL_WINDOWEVENT    = 0x200, /**< Window state change */
SDL_SYSWMEVENT,             /**< System specific event */

/* Keyboard events */
SDL_KEYDOWN        = 0x300, /**< Key pressed */
SDL_KEYUP,                  /**< Key released */
```

So they are just defined with such spread values. The rationale behind this is to allow adding new values without breaking backwards compatibility while keeping certain enumerator values grouped.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misusing events. In your case:

```
if (event.type == SDL_QUIT || event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
```

However, `event` is basically a huge union and fields inside `event.key` are only valid when `event.type` is one of key-related events.

Maybe here lies your problem? To me that sounds like you misinterpreting what `SDL_PollEvent` returns.

EDIT:
The person before me seems to be more on topic, however my point still stands. Admitedly, not exactly what you're asking about but you might still watch out for that.